# PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS Showing different Values

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable, file-mapping, nt

so I am currently attempting to locally map my suspended thread when I pop my program into CFF explorer it says that the value of PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS is 00004550:
[image]

however while attempting to map it by myself my value comes out to be 00400080:
[image]

```c
typedef struct pe {
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER peDH;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peNH;


} pe;

PE.peDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)imgBase;
PE.peNH = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((u_char*)PE.peDH + PE.peDH->e_lfanew);
printf("[?] - NT Headers section is located at: 0x%x\n", PE.peNH);
```

Comment: You are printing the *pointer*, not the value it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says that the value of PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS is 00004550

No, it doesn't. Look at it again more carefully. It actually says the `Signature` field of the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` struct is `00004550`. But you are not printing the `Signature`, you are printing the `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS` pointer itself. Not the same thing.

Change your print to this instead:

```
printf("[?] - NT Headers Signature is: 0x%08x\n", PE.peNH->Signature);
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, sorry didn't realize that this was in fact a pointer from reading the docs.